# Powers of matrices with constant diagonals

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a square matrix where each ``diagonal'' is  constant, for example 
$A= \left( \matrix {
a & b & c & d \cr
e & a & b & c \cr
f & e & a & b \cr
g & f & e & a \cr
}\right)$. Is there a shortcut for finding $A^n$?

Edit
[Sufficient Conditions for a power of Toeplitz matrix being Toeplitz](http://www.ccsenet.org/journal/index.php/jmr/article/viewFile/32011/18617)

Comment: Jordanize it?${}$

Comment: @GitGud I want it symbolically, that is $a,b,c,\cdots$ are not numbers. And The eigenvalues of the symbolic matrix are not simple expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called Toeplitz matrices.  Powers of Toeplitz matrices are not Toeplitz in general. Suppose your matrix is $m \times m$ with 
entries $a_{ij} = f(i-j)$.  The $(i,j)$ element of $A^n$ is the sum of products
$\prod_{k=1}^{n} f(d_k)$ over all $(d_1, \ldots, d_n) \in \{-m+1, \ldots, m-1\}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^n d_k = j - i$ and all partial sums $1-i \le \sum_{k=1}^r d_k \le m-i$ for $1 \le r < n$.